# AppEngine no host given exception

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlopen

I've got a Python app, that uses `urllib.urlopen`. It works fine on `dev_appserver.py`, but throws `[Errno http error] no host given` error on my GAE production server. The code is exactly the same, the url, it connects to, is hardcoded. I'm out of ideas, what could be wrong.

**UPD**: the code:

```
def getPic(url):
    sock = urllib.urlopen("http://www.quicklatex.com/latex.f?formula="+(url.replace("&amp;", "&")))
    if "0" in sock.readline() :
     return sock.readline().partition(" ")[0]
    else:
     return ""
```

It fetches the page, returned by quicklatex.com website. First line contains of number of errors, second -- of link to the generated image, followed by space and a number. I'm fetching the url of the picture. The `url` variable itself contains some LaTeX code.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reviewing [the URL Fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html) documentation? Can you show us the URL?